# Vector and HWND Zero memory error c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, vector, hwnd

I wanted to create multiple windows ..So rather than writing them over and over again,I decided to use vector to keep list of all **HWND** and update them as programn proceeds.But Its doesnt seem to work as expected .. it is giving me a access violation error .

i tried initializing the vector.But nothing seems to work

WindoManager.h

```
  #include<windowsx.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class WindowManager{

    // Constructor
    WindowManager();

    // Destructor
    ~WindowManager();

private:
    vector<HWND> wnds;
    HWND hwnd;

public:
    void CreateNewWindow(HINSTANCE hinst,WNDCLASSEX * ex,HWND * Parent,HWND * ReturnWind,int Width,int Height,int X,int Y);
    void ShowWindows(int);
    int HandleMseeages();

};
```

WindowManager.cpp

```
#include"WindowManager.h"

WindowManager::WindowManager()
{


}

void WindowManager::CreateNewWindow(HINSTANCE hinst,WNDCLASSEX * ex,HWND * Parent,HWND * ReturnWind,int Width,int Height,int X,int Y)
{
    if(Parent == NULL)
    {
      hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,ex->lpszClassName,ex->lpszMenuName,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,X,Y,Width,Height,NULL,NULL,hinst,NULL);
        wnds.push_back(hwnd);
        *ReturnWind = hwnd;
    }
}

void WindowManager::ShowWindows(int show)
{
    for(vector<HWND>::iterator it = wnds.begin();it != wnds.end() ; ++it)
    {
        ShowWindow(*it,show);
    }
}


int WindowManager::HandleMseeages()
{
    MSG msg;

 for(int i=0;i< wnds.size();++i)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg,wnds[i],0,0,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                return 0;
        }
    }

 return 1;
}
```

And the function gets called from source.cpp

```
....//Removed unwanted code

WindowManager * WndManager = {0};

    WndManager->CreateNewWindow(hinst,&classex,NULL,&hwnd,500,500,0,0);
    WndManager->ShowWindows(cmdshow);
```

i dont know whats wrong..Please do help me out

**Thanks**

Comment: Looks to me like you're dereferencing null...

Comment: Unrelated: I'm trying to figure out the sense in that peek message queue in the first place, which I don't think will pick up thread-messages such as he WM_QUIT you're expecting. Why not just a regular message loop ?

Comment: Hi @WhozCraig  Thanks for the reply .But what did you mean by regular loops. Could you please explain thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
WindowManager * WndManager = {0};
```

You are declaring a pointer without allocating an object and calling it's constructor.

Allocate an object as:

```
WindowManager * WndManager = new WindowManager;
```

Or just simply define it in the stack and use the right calls (as suggested by *Richard Hodges*):

```
WindowManager WndManager;

WndManager.CreateNewWindow(hinst,&classex,NULL,&hwnd,500,500,0,0);
WndManager.ShowWindows(cmdshow);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help.. But by assigning it to zero.. All Wanted to do was allocate a memory block..As I read somewhere that by doing so The constructor automatically gets called ... Is it true??   ( I used a lot of c# . So a bit newnew to c++)

Comment: Assigning zero to pointer just make the value of the address zero (which is usually used to indicate `NULL`, or a pointer that points to nothing.) You need to actually allocate a storage using `new` or `malloc()`. `new` calls the constructor automatically for you. `malloc()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WindowManager WndManager{};

WndManager.CreateNewWindow(hinst,&classex,NULL,&hwnd,500,500,0,0);
WndManager.ShowWindows(cmdshow);
```

Comment: To note the `{}` is not necessary.

Comment: And why not simply `WindowManager WndManager;` ? or else `WindowManager *WndManager = new WindowManager();` if OP wants a pointer.

Comment: or even auto `auto mgr_ptr = std::make_unique<WindowManager>();`